# I keep getting this error in my code. Why does this keep happening? Thanks

Tags: python-3.x

This is a method overload

```
    class Point():
        def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.coords = (self.x, self.y)


        def move(self, x, y):
            self.x += x
            self.y += y


        def __add__(self, p):
            return Point(self.x + p.x, self.y + p.y)

        def __sub__(self, p):
            return Point(self.x - p.x, self.y - p.y)

        def __mul__(self, p):
            return (self.x * p.x + self.y * p.y)




        def __str__(self):  
            return  str(self.x)  str(self.y)

    p1 = Point(3,4)
    p2 = Point(3,2)
    p3 = Point(1,3)
    p4 = Point(0,1)
    p5 = p1 + p2
    p6 = p4 - p1
    p7 = p2*p3

    print(p5, p6, p7)
```

I keep getting this error. Can someone explain why this is the incorrect syntax

return  str(self.x)  str(self.y)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

This will not return a string

```
return  str(self.x),  str(self.y)
```

You should return it as a string

```
return  "(" + str(self.x) + ", " + str(self.y) + ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Invalid syntax is because you are trying to return 2 variables you need to comma separate them.

```
    def __str__(self):  
        return  str(self.x),  str(self.y)
```

Comment: When I put a comma between the two variables I get this error

Comment: print(p5, p6, p7)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)

Comment: Also why can't  I return variables.